# Как при клике убрать класс у другого блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так что-бы число появлялась только в том списке, в котором кликнули по пункту? Сейчас на какой бы пункт я не кликнул появляется сразу в двух колонках, а нужно что-бы только в одной. Спасибо

```js
const catalogItems = document.querySelectorAll('.select-catalog__item');
const catalogCounts = document.querySelectorAll('.select-catalog__title-count');

  const updateActiveCount = () => {
    catalogCounts.forEach(count => {
      const activeCount = [...catalogItems].filter(i => i.classList.contains('_active')).length
      count.innerText = activeCount
      if (activeCount > 0) {
        count.classList.add('_active')
      } else {
        count.classList.remove('_active')
      }
    });
  }

for (const item of catalogItems) {
  item.onclick = ({ target }) => {
    const isActive = target.classList.toggle('_active')
    updateActiveCount()
  }
}
```

```css
.select-catalog{
  display: flex;
}

.select-catalog__title-count {
  display: none;
}

.select-catalog__title-count._active {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #a89583;
  border-radius: 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum"on, "lnum"on;
}

.select-catalog__item {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  border: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: math.div(24, 16);
  background-color: rgba(168, 149, 131, 0.08);
}

.select-catalog__item._active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__selects select-catalog">
  <div class="select-catalog__column">
    <div class="select-catalog__items">
      <div class="select-catalog__title">
        <div class="select-catalog__title-count">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="select-catalog__list">
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          One size
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XXS
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XS
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-catalog__column">
    <div class="select-catalog__items">
      <div class="select-catalog__title">
        <div class="select-catalog__title-count">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="select-catalog__list">
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          One size
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XXS
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XS
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как сделать так что-бы число появлялась только в том списке, в котором кликнули по пункту?

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
document.querySelector('.catalog__selects').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let o = e.target.closest('.select-catalog__item')
  if (!o) return
  o.classList.toggle('_active')
  o = o.closest('.select-catalog__items')
  const n = o.querySelectorAll('.select-catalog__list ._active').length
  o = o.querySelector('.select-catalog__title-count')
  o.textContent = n ? n : ''
  if (n > 0) {
    o.classList.add('_active')
  } else {
    o.classList.remove('_active')
  }
})
```

```css
.select-catalog {
  display: flex;
}

.select-catalog__title-count {
  display: none;
}

.select-catalog__title-count._active {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #a89583;
  border-radius: 9px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  font-feature-settings: "tnum"on, "lnum"on;
}

.select-catalog__item {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  border: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: math.div(24, 16);
  background-color: rgba(168, 149, 131, 0.08);
}

.select-catalog__item._active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog__selects select-catalog">
  <div class="select-catalog__column">
    <div class="select-catalog__items">
      <div class="select-catalog__title">
        <div class="select-catalog__title-count">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="select-catalog__list">
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          One size
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XXS
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XS
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="select-catalog__column">
    <div class="select-catalog__items">
      <div class="select-catalog__title">
        <div class="select-catalog__title-count">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="select-catalog__list">
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          One size
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XXS
        </div>
        <div class="select-catalog__item">
          XS
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```